# Getting an indexed collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would like to get an indexed collection from an eloquent call to get a specific item:

```
$items = FeedItem::all();
$specific_item = $items[4];
```

Or is it possible to do something like:

```
$items->get('id', 4);
```

where id is the attribute and 4 is the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FeedItem::all()` will return a [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Collection.html).

To get a specific model you can use the [find](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Collection.html#7-21) method:

```
$items = FeedItem::all();
$item = $items->find($id);
```

For more methods of the Collection class see [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections) and [the api](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html).